# Update two log tables for visits and summary per day

Tags: php, object, relational-database

I'm trying to log page visits and count number of visitors.

I have two tables, one is a raw log of all visitors, second table will be summary of the first table only with number of visits of pages by date. Since the second table is generated of the first and first table is cleared, I'm thinking to have it processed on that page load by users themselves. But multiple users would end up triggering it multiple time.

Is there a way so that it can only be triggered once at any one time by object locking. I'm not sure I'm making sense or there is even such thing. As I will be hosting the web apps on a 3rd party hosting with no access to creating cron or some sort. Or any better way doing it?

Comment: Maybe you could use a single table and calculate the results on the fly in your log viewer?

Comment: What about updating the summary table as well by using `SET count = count + 1` sort of update? If you don't have cron everything else looks quite expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use http://www.webalizer.org/ or http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ to make statistics.
If you still want to make it by yourself, don't calculate statistic on each request, you can just log timestamp,IP and PHPSESSID (this is important).

Then specify scheduled task once a day when server load is minimal (eg 03:00) and aggregate using group by.PHPSESSID is important, because it will be key to log "sessions" instead of requests.

Comment: I need to provide custom graph for user in the app possibly with no other installation required. I am currently logging the user agent too. Would it be redundant to keep?

Comment: It depends on which data you want to report.If your statistics will not include user-agent, there is no reason to log them.However, you should log session ID as key, then you can do something like select count(1) as visit_count from access_table group by session_id where visit_date between start_date and end_date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external Service to call a script to do the work. E. g. http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/ as an example, but there are many such (free) services available.
But I also recommend to use some advanced statistics tool as rkosegi recommended.

Comment: This looks like what i'm looking for. Looking at it now. Thanks!